# Django: configuring multiple domains for a website?

Tags: django, url, dns, sites

how can i manage in django multiple domains? Our website will be configured like this

```
jobs.site.com
cars.site.com
homes.site.com
jobs.site.co.uk
cars.site.co.uk
....
```

and so on. basically, we will have three third level domains (jobs,cars,homes) and some country specific domains.

i'm actually working locally with urls like "localhost/uk/jobs/" but when we're going live we should use jobs.site.co.uk instead...

i really have no clue, nor i know what i should search on google, can somebody please provide me a brief but full "howto" to configure my settings (or full django app) to do exactly what i need?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you run your Django projects, but to me it looks like `xyz.site.com` could be different projects. If they all share the same code, see the second paragraph below.

Take a look at the [Django "sites" framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) if you need to distinguish between different hosts within a single Django project (like `jobs.site.co.uk` and `jobs.site.com`).

Answer (score 5):

If they share the same code or database, you will have to retrieve the subdomain name creating your own subdomain middleware.

Have a look to this http://thingsilearned.com/2009/01/05/using-subdomains-in-django/